# Prove the congruency of the following triangles

Tags: geometry

$l$ and $m$ are two parallel lines intersected by another pair of parallel lines $p$ and $q$. Prove that $\triangle ABC\cong\triangle CDA$.

[image]

I tried the following,
$\angle D=\angle C$

But how do I solve this problem now?

Comment: It's just angle-side-angle. In this case, the side is the shared segment AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to prove $\triangle ABC\cong \triangle CDA$. Evidently $AC=CA$. Since line $l$ is parallel to line $m$ we have $\angle ACB = \angle CAD$. Since line $p$ is parallel to line $q$ we have $\angle BAC = \angle DCA$.

Answer (score 0):

We have a side-angle-angle congruence here, since

1. Side $CA$ is common to both triangles.
2. $\angle DAC$ = $\angle ACB$ (Alternate angles since $l$ is parallel to $m$)
3. $\angle BAC = \angle ACD$ (Alternate angles since $p$ is parallel to $q$)

I believe what you referred to as $\angle C$ is $\angle DCm$, which is outside the triangle and hence can't be used to prove congruence.